# c# ManagementObjectSearcher used for finding process (and its description) with PID

Tags: c#, .net

Im working on a program which should list me processes and when i click on certain process it should give me its description.

My idea(Actually i modified something similar what i found on web) was to use ManagementObjectSearcher with sql statement ("Select * From Win32_Process WHERE ProcessID="+a); where "a" is string variable which contains process ID.For some processes its working(chrome,calculator for example) and for some it doesnt(svchost,tiltweelmouse and so on).

```
    private void Lista_procesa_prikaz_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        string a = Lista_procesa_prikaz.Items[Lista_procesa_prikaz.FocusedItem.Index].SubItems[1].Text;
        var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * From Win32_Process WHERE ProcessID="+a);
        var proces = searcher.Get();
        foreach (var process in proces)
        {
            var processName = process["Name"];
            var processPath = process["ExecutablePath"];

            if (processPath != null)
            {
                var fileVersionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(processPath.ToString());
                var processDescription = fileVersionInfo.FileDescription;
                Description_textbox.Text = processDescription.ToString();
            }
       }
    }
```

IF someone could spot mistake here i would be really happy,
Any help is appreciated

Thank you

EDIT: Partially solved problem,if anyone even cares,platform need to be set to x64(in my case).Go to **Project**,*yourProjectName* **properties**,**build**,**platform target**:x64

Comment: As a _guess_ I'd say those procs that it fails on are running as admin.

Comment: @Mathemats Hmm,could be,so how should i even run my program from c# as admin to avoid those errors?Also,i tryed adding" else textbox.text=null" after "if(processPath!=null)",and even then sometimes error pops up,unhandled exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it must be from `ManagementObjectSearcher` but may I suggest a managed class that gets the same data.

```
var procs = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses()
    .Where(x => x.Id == 3116);

foreach(var p in procs)
    Console.WriteLine(p.ProcessName + p.Id);
```

Attempting to read the path to the using both approaches will throw if you don't have elevated privileges. As for getting those privileges, consider [using a manifest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx) for that.